# Fix a formula with fraction 1/2 in subscript mode

Tags: math-mode, mtpro, newtxmath, newtx

At this time for my book I am writing some formulas for radioactive decay. I'm  using actually `newtxtext` package as a text font and `mt2pro` as a mathematical character and formula font. In the attached code I use `newtxmath` so that everyone can compile it regularly keeping in mind that the situation is the same using `mt2pro`. Precisely I would like to write the fraction `1/2` similar to the image below (green rectangle),

[image]

In other words, the backslash should be very close to the number 1 and 2, because as you can see in the formula (2), the expression is not only not visually good.

We appreciate your suggestions and your knowledge to make the visualization of my formulas better (especially the exponent of the formula (2)).

**Here my MWE for 2nd image:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}   

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
T_{1/2}=\frac {\ln 2}{\lambda}=\tau \ln 2<\tau
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
N(t)=N_0e^{-\frac{t\ln 2}{T_{1/2}}}=N_0e^{\ln 2^{-\frac t{T_{1/2}}}}=N_0{2}^{-\frac{t}{T_{1/2}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The digit 1 is much thinner than the other digits. Most fonts, however, define it with a bounding box equal to the ones for the other digits, for the sake of alignment in tables.

You can solve the special case by defining a suitable command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\one}{\mspace{-1mu}1\mspace{-1.5mu}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
T_{\one/2}=\frac {\ln 2}{\lambda}=\tau \ln 2<\tau
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
N(t)=N_0e^{-\frac{t\ln 2}{T_{\one/2}}}=
N_0e^{\ln 2^{-\frac t{T_{\one/2}}}}=N_0{2}^{-\frac{t}{T_{\one/2}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't touch the slash.

[image]

I would also omit the step with the fraction at second level superscript: it is unreadable and actually an easy application of logarithms. A short explanation after the equation is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}   
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
T_{\nicefrac{1}{2}}=\frac {\ln 2}{\lambda}=\tau \ln 2<\tau
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
N(t)=N_0e^{-\frac{t\ln 2}{T_{\nicefrac{1}{2}}}}=N_0e^{\ln 2^{-\frac t{T_{\nicefrac{1}{2}}}}}=N_0{2}^{-\frac{t}{T_{\nicefrac{1}{2}}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to the party, but better late than never, right?

Since you set the tag `mtpro` in your query, I think it's ok to recommend that you use `mtpro2` (possibly its 'lite' subset) rather than  `newtxmath` as the main math font package. `mtpro2` employs optical sizing for first- and second-order subscripts and superscripts; as a result, "thin" glyphs such as `1` don't appear nearly as skinny as those of `newtxmath` do.

Second, I'd create a macro called, say, `\teeonehalf`, and define it as follows:

```
\newcommand\teeonehalf{T_{\mkern-2mu 1\mkern-1.5mu/2}}
```

By "tucking in" the term 1/2 a bit more below the `T` character, and by reducing the distance between `1` and `/`, the `1` character starts to look a bit less skinny.

Last but not least, I'd also like to recommend that you use `\exp` and inline math notation wherever possible, and thus replace, say, `N_0e^{\ln 2^{-\frac t{T_{1/2}}}}` with `N_0\exp\bigl(\ln 2^{-t/\teeonehalf}\bigr)`. I think the legibility of the equation is much enhanced by these typographic devices.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}  
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\newcommand\teeonehalf{T_{\mkern-2mu 1\mkern-1.5mu/2}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\teeonehalf= \ln 2/\lambda=\tau \ln 2<\tau
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
N(t)=N_0\exp(-t\ln 2/\teeonehalf)
    =N_0\exp\bigl(\ln 2^{-t/\teeonehalf}\bigr)
    =N_0\, 2^{-t/\teeonehalf}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It was actually a surprise that I voted positively for the elegance of the code and especially for the explanation. Thank you so much for your kindness.